# Evince 3.10 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, evince

I'm using Document Viewer (Evince) 3.4.0 on Ubuntu 12.04, but would like to use version 3.10, since it has a new feature which is very useful in my work. I've used the link provided here 
https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/evince/
but it just shows me that Evince is already installed (the older version).

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: You wrongly mentioned the link.Ubuntu 12.04 is `precise` not `saucy`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Read the quesiton. The OP wants to install the version of Evince from Saucy (v3.10 which was linked) into Precise.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid a lot of black magic shuffeling repositories for just one packet is a bit over the top so I tried another way to install it.

1) `apt-get remove evince` remove the current version

2) downloaded the evince from http://packages.ubuntu.com/nl/saucy/evince

3) `apt-get install gdebi`

4)  use gdebi to install the evince that just downloaded

5) against my expectations I landed in dependency hell!

A lot of times this method works okay but this time I had over 50(!) cumulative dependencies.
Added to this: a few libs were *very* core bound to the system so the chance of breaking the system was extreme.

Conclusion: This was not the way to install evince 3.10 in Ubuntu Precise.

Comment: He was using precise,not saucy.Try to update the link.

Comment: Read again, Avinash. He has Ubuntu Precise installed and using evince from Ubuntu Precise, but he *wants* to run the evince from Ubuntu Saucy on Ubuntu Precise.

Comment: Evince 3.10 depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3). Precise has 2.32.1-0ubuntu2, etc. Step 5 requires a lot more than you are indicating and may break other things.

Comment: A few dependencies are solvable...if the number of dependencies are getting overwhelming, it is easy to reverse the steps (I have done that before). How many dependencies do you estimate he would have to solve ? Your answer might save him some work.

Comment: @Thom, with respect, this isn't my answer, it's yours. I'm just trying to help you improve it. :) You may want to look into the dependency situation in more detail and add it to your answer.

Comment: @chaskes Yes, sorry, you are right. I will do that :) [edit] The amount of dependencies is indeed extremely overwhelming. shall I delete my answer ?

Comment: @Thom No, don't delete. Take out the part about thanking me, it's not needed in this case. Just expand on step 5 with a realistic look at the scope of the problem. My point was not to say you were wrong (technically you are not) just to suggest you get more info on a point like that before posting.

Comment: @chaskes Done, and thank you for your kind words.

Comment: Indeed, I began the whole dependency updating thing, and it got deeper and deeper. When I came to «Breaks existing package etc.» I decided to end it there. So is there any way to do this?

Comment: no,it needs upgrading of half the system. I just read that some people even did some attempts to compile evince with static libraries but they gave up because of the endless dependencies to solve. The only way is to upgrade to saucy.

Answer (score 1):

[There is a way but you won't like it](http://jaliste.blogspot.de/2013/04/the-jhbuild-experience.html). Jhbuild can create a local GNOME app installation in a folder of your choice with all necessary dependencies and libraries. It won't affect your system because it bypasses the package manager and only downloads and installs files to the folder you chose.

However:

- You will have to fetch about 1GB of GNOME dependencies
- You will have to compile them (which depending on your system might
  take quite long)
- The end product might not integrate that well with your system. At
  least from my experience it didn't, with icons not being displayed,
  no proper Zeitgeist integration and issues with settings, etc.

All things considered you will definitely have to ask yourself if it's actually worth the effort to you. Hopefully click packages will solve issues like these in the future.

Comment: It does seem a long way to go. I guess I'm going to have to install Ubuntu 13.10 side by side with 12.04 just to use Evince 3.10. It might sound silly, but it might be best. Thanks.